# How to run a static parallel for loop without the main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to execute a funtion with multithreads, without using main thread. So this is what I want:

```
  # pragma omp parallel num_threads(9)
  {
     // do something
     # pragma omp for schedule(static,1)
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        func(i); // random stuff
  }
```

So I want func() to be executed just by 8 threads, without main thread. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to schedule with a chunk size of 1? This is in most cases suboptimal in terms of cache locality. If you don't have a good reason to do so, you should use ```static``` without specifying a chunk size, such that the maximal chunk size is going to be used. With non-static scheduling one might want to have a chunk size of 1 because one normally expects different loop iterations to encompass different amounts of work.

Comment: @dreamcrash Any thoughts about the difference between our solutions? ;)

Answer (score 1):

> So I want func() to be executed just by 8 threads, without main
> thread. Is that possible somehow?

Yes, you can do it. However, you will have to implement the functionality of

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static,1)
```

since, explicitly using the aforementioned clause will *make* the compiler *automatically* divide the iterations of the loop among the threads in the team, including the *master* thread of that team, which in your code example will be also the *main* thread. The code could look like the following:

```
# pragma omp parallel num_threads(9) 
{
     // do something
      int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
      int total_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
      if(thread_id != 0) // all threads but the master thread
      {
        thread_id--; // shift all the ids
        total_threads = total_threads - 1;
        for(int i = thread_id ; i < 10; i += total_threads)
            func(i); // random stuff
      }
      #pragma omp barrier
}
```

First, we ensure that all threads except the *master* executed the loop to be parallelized (*i.e.,* `if(thread_id != 0)`), then we divided the iterations of the loop among the remaining threads (*i.e.,* `for(int i = thread_id ; i < 10; i += total_threads)`), and finally we ensure that all threads wait for each other at the end of the parallel region (*i.e.,* `#pragma omp barrier`).

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't important which thread doesn't do the loop, another option would be to combine `sections` with the loop. This means nesting parallelism, which one should be very careful with, but it should work:

```c
#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp section
    { /* work for one thread */ }
      #pragma omp section
      {
          #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) schedule(static, 1)
          for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { /* ... */ }
      }
}
```

The main problem here is, that most likely one of those sections will be taking much longer than the other one, meaning that in the worst case (loop faster than first section) all but one thread are doing nothing most of the time.

If you really need the master thread to be outside the parallel region this might work (not tested):

```c
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    #pragma omp master
    { /* work for master thread, other thread is NOT waiting */ }
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8) schedule(static, 1)
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { /* ... */ }
        }
}
```

There is no guarantee that the `master` thread wont be computing the `single` region as well, but if your cores aren't over-occupied it should at least be unlikely. One could even argue that if the second thread from the outer parallel region doesn't reach the single region in time, it is better that the master thread also has a chance of going in there, even if that means, that the second thread doesn't get anything to do.

As the `single` region should only have an implicit barrier at it's end, while the `master` region doesn't contain any implicit barriers, they should potentially be executed in parallel as longs as the `master` region is in front of the `single` region. This assumes that the `single` region is well-implemented, such that every thread has a chance of computing it. This isn't guaranteed by the standard, I think.

EDIT:
These solutions require nested parallelism to work, which is disabled by default in most implementations. It can be activated via the environment variable `OMP_NESTED` or by calling `omp_set_nested()`.